# How do i prevent from printscreen of my webpage?

Tags: php, webpage-screenshot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Taking screenshot of a webpage programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316564/taking-screenshot-of-a-webpage-programmatically)
> [How can i disable print screen for a web page in all browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5938466/how-can-i-disable-print-screen-for-a-web-page-in-all-browser)

Is there any possibilities to prevent  printscreen for a webpage? If yes, how can i do that?

Comment: What if the client takes a picture of the monitor?

Comment: printing you can stop by using ```@media print {
    .noprint {
       visibility: hidden;
    }
 }``` add '``noprint``' class to the element which content you want to hide on print screen. I'm not sure how to stop this in case of screenshot

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There is no way that you can stop a client machine from being able to print screen.

Answer (score 16):

As the old hacker proverb says, if the information can be read, it can be copied.

There is no way to prevent <kbd>Print Screen</kbd>.

Answer (score 9):

You will never be able to prevent users from copying content off your website. 
What is displayed on the users monitor can be print screen'd, whatever you try to do. All effords will only decrease usability, but won't prevent copying.

Comment: Netflix found a way to prevent screenshots of a streaming video, so apparently it's possible.