# Can I disable Screenshot/screen capture in react web app?

Tags: reactjs, web-applications, screenshot, disable

I would like to know whether we can disable screenshot or screen capture in firebase react progressive web app ? Please reply on priority

I am looking for the reply as soon as possible

Comment: Simply put, no.

Comment: Thanks Rico for your quick response ,would like to see an official document to conclude this. @RicoHancock

Comment: You can see more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12429439/what-are-the-ways-to-prevent-users-to-take-screenshot-of-a-webpage. Screen captures are handled by the Operating Systems and not the web server.