# How to block auto-scroll functionality of full page auto-scroll screenshot extensions?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a membership website where I want to prevent people from taking full page screenshots of the wall of text I have in my members area, using auto-scroll screenshot browser extensions like: [Fireshot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/take-webpage-screenshots/mcbpblocgmgfnpjjppndjkmgjaogfceg?hl=en) and [GoFullPage](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gofullpage-full-page-scre/fdpohaocaechififmbbbbbknoalclacl?hl=en).

I am looking for a script I can embed in my page that will break the auto-scroll functionality of these screenshot extensions. When the screenshot is being taken if the auto-scroll feature can be somehow broken, it will prevent the whole page from being captured in the screenshot using these extensions.

Not sure if its possible but it will definitely be very useful in stopping people from stealing the text content behind the paywall. I have enabled a script that prevents copy and right click. Now the only thing they can do is take auto-scroll screenshots of the long page. If I can prevent that as well, the only thing pirates can do is take multiple manual screenshots of the long page and manually stitch it together in photoshop. Just trying to make life difficult for them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do i prevent from printscreen of my webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7427286/how-do-i-prevent-from-printscreen-of-my-webpage)

Comment: You cam wastes hours of time trying to make it difficult.    You might also need an army to  prevent users from taking pictures from their smartphones a foot or two away from the monitor.  How important is your copyright?

Comment: This can't be done. Even if it could, annoying users who _have_ paid you by making their shit break to prevent them from sharing with those who _have **not**_ paid will engender customer disloyalty.

Comment: I am actually only trying to break the auto-scroll feature of these extensions not block screenshots altogether. I have updated my question for added clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Screenshots are not controlled by the web browser, they are controlled by software running on the user's operating system and cannot be remotely controlled by a web server. There's a lot you can do to make it harder (javascript to capture the prtsc key press and return false, flicker different quadrants of the screen at intervals so that it's too fast for human eyes to really tell but so that the whole screen never shows at once, etc) but fundamentally anyone who's even vaguely tech-savy can bypass this in about 5 seconds. Also, a google search should have answered this for you in way less time than it took to ask.
You cannot block the print screen button or the snipping tool in Windows or the Grab application included with Mac OS or any other tool on any other OS. I hope I helped

Comment: I am actually only trying to break the auto-scroll feature of these extensions not block screenshots altogether. I have updated my question for added clarity.