# how to disable print screen button in the web page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<html> 
<head> 
<script style="text/javascript">
        function Gallerytext(){
            if (window.clipboardData.setData('text','')){
                setInterval("window.clipboardData.setData('text','')",20);  
                document.getElementById("LoadImage").innerHTML = ""; //***Code to write image src will go here..
            }else{
                alert ("Clipboard is required to view the client area. Please allow access to continue.");
            }
        }
    </script>
</head> 

<body onLoad="javascript:Gallerytext()"> 
YOU TRY TO COPY AND PASTE THIS SCREEN, AND ALL THE ACTIVE SCREENS 


</body> 
</html>
```

print screen not disable any body explain how to disable print screen button in web page?

Comment: you want to avoid that an user can use his printscreen button on your webpage? If true - its not possible at all, because the printscreen functionality comes from the OS. You cant and shouldnt restrict that.

Comment: Take a look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5938466/how-can-i-disable-print-screen-for-a-web-page-in-all-browser