# Do not allow screen printing in a progressive web app - angular / reactjs

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs, typescript, progressive-web-apps

I would like to know if there is any solution to lock the screen print, and if possible the screen recording (although I find it difficult), from a progressive web app.

Some mobile applications have this functionality, however I would like to know the possibility of this in progressive web apps, without installation.

Grateful!

Comment: Welcome to SO. It is normally good practice to include example code and what you have tried so far. –

Comment: You will never have that ability. A user can always take a screenshot on their android phone. Or take a picture of their screen. Do you know of apps that prevent taking a screenshot?

Comment: Thank you all for the tips and answers.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible in a web app at the moment. You have maybe found out already, but already a lot of people asked this and it is simply not possible. In a native Android/iOS app you can catch this behaviour but the browser can't.

Here are some resources that talk about this, some have glitchy tricks to do this but it's never screenshot proof :

- [What are the ways to prevent users to take screenshot of a webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12429439/what-are-the-ways-to-prevent-users-to-take-screenshot-of-a-webpage)
- [How do i prevent from printscreen of my webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7427286/how-do-i-prevent-from-printscreen-of-my-webpage)
- [How can I disable print-screen functionality for a webpage in all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5938466/how-can-i-disable-print-screen-functionality-for-a-webpage-in-all-browsers)

One tip that maybe sounds obvious, just don't put things on the internet you don't want to be saved, or whatever you are trying to protect your content from.

If you want to prevent copy-paste that's possible, but not what the question is about.